# Filtering QFilesystemModel

Tags: qt, qlistview, qfilesystemmodel

I'm using a *QFileSystemModel* with a *QListview* to display all files from a directory.
I'd like to filter that model to display some categories of files like :

- textual files : *.txt *.csv *.tab
- music : *.mp3 *.flac *.ogg
- movies : *.avi *.mkv

My current code is :

```
  MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
     Filemodel = new QFileSystemModel(this)                      ;
     Filemodel->setFilter( QDir::NoDotAndDotDot | QDir::Files )  ;
     proxy_model = new QSortFilterProxyModel();

     proxy_model ->setDynamicSortFilter(true);
     proxy_model ->setSourceModel( Filemodel ); 
     proxy_model ->setFilterKeyColumn(0);
     ui->Filtered_tbView->setModel( proxy_model )                ;
}
```

(...)

```
/* combobox event to select file type to filter */
 void MainWindow::on_FSFilter_Combo_currentIndexChanged(int index)
{
 proxy_model->setFilterWildcard("*.txt");  // just a simple example here
 ui->Filtered_tbView->setModel( proxy_model )                ;
}
```

That code doesn't display anything while all type of files are present in the directory.

Besides, things I've tried that wasn't fine for me (pointers may be useful for further readers) :

- setNameFilters : work well but lets show all files (unfiltered are just greyed)
- [the Custom Sort/Filter Model Example](http://www.trinitydesktop.org/docs/qt4/itemviews-customsortfiltermodel.html) -> while using QSortFilterProxyModel this example is somewhat too complicated to just filter out the file extentions, besides it uses regexp that is not the best method when using many filters like here.
- I've also found an [interesting snippet from qt-project](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Filter_Columns_in_a_QFileSystemModel) but couldn't found out how to implement it for rows with multiple extensions

Answer (score 10):

The easiest way is to use `QFileSystemModel::setNameFilters`.

With the property `QFileSystemModel::nameFilterDisables` you can choose between filtered out files being disabled or hidden.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    Filemodel = new QFileSystemModel(this)                      ;
    Filemodel->setFilter( QDir::NoDotAndDotDot | QDir::Files )  ;

    QStringList filters;
    filters << "*.txt";

    Filemodel.setNameFilters(filters);
    Filemodel.setNameFilterDisables(false);

    ui->Filtered_tbView->setModel( Filemodel )                  ;
}
```