# Qt: QFileSystemModel Filter Out Directories (not files) by expression

Tags: c++, qt, qfile

How can i filter out Folders? I looked for QDir::Filters [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qdir.html#Filters-typedef): but i cannot see how to filter by expression. I Want to Hide Folders Starting with "A00*"

[image]

I tried to use nameFilters, but then the folders are just becoming grey:

```
QStringList filters;
filters <<"Cloth";
dirModel->setNameFilters(filters);
```

[image]

Comment: What if you try to set `dirModel->setNameFilterDisables(false);`?

Comment: Can you please write this as an answer? And how can i inverse the expression?

Comment: Why not create a subclass of ProxyModel and just create your own filter to not display desired directories

Comment: @SebastianLange i have to definetely look into at, for now i just need a solution, i already looked into ProxyModel.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filtering QFilesystemModel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17166866/filtering-qfilesystemmodel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a QFileSystemModel's property that defines how items (files, directories) should be visualized is they do not pass the name filter. It is `nameFilterDisables`. By default this property is true, i.e. items that do not pass the name filter are disabled. For your case you have to disable this property to make non filtered items hidden:

```
dirModel->setNameFilterDisables(false);
```

Comment: Can you write how the invert the filter?

Comment: @user1767754, what do you mean?

Comment: filters<<"^Cloth"; How can i use wildcards, to inverse an expression?